Owned type property loses value after DbSet.Add is called in Entity Framework Core
I'm currently working on a project using Entity Framework Core and I've encountered an issue with owned types. I have a structure similar to the following:
class MainEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual List<SecondEntity>? Seconds { get; set; }
    public MyOwnedType MyOwnedTypeStart { get; set; } = null!;
    public MyOwnedType MyOwnedTypeEnd { get; set; } = null!;
}

class SecondEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid MainEntityId { get; set; }
    public virtual MainEntity? MainEntity { get; set; }
    public virtual List<ThirdEntity>? Third { get; set; }
    public MyOwnedType MyOwnedType { get; set; } = null!;
}

class ThirdEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid SecondEntityId { get; set; }
    public virtual SecondEntity? SecondEntity { get; set; }
    public MyOwnedType MyOwnedType { get; set; } = null!;
}

public record MyOwnedType 
{
    public EMonth Month { get; init; }
    public ushort Year { get; init; }
}

public enum EMonth
{
    January = 1,
    February = 2,
    March = 3,
    April = 4,
    May = 5,
    June = 6,
    July = 7,
    August = 8,
    September = 9,
    October = 10,
    November = 11,
    December = 12,
    ExtraMonth = 13
}

In this structure, MyOwnedType is an owned type. When I create a new MainEntity and add it to the context using AddAsync, the MyOwnedType property in ThirdEntity is set to null, right after the AddAsync call. Note that the MyOwnedType property in SecondEntity is not set to null. This happens even though MyOwnedType has a value right before the AddAsync call.
Here's the code where I add the entity:
public virtual Task AddAsync(MainEntity entity)
{
    // ... some code here ...

    return dbSet.AddAsync(entity).AsTask();
}

The MyOwnedType owned type is configured as follows:
builder.OwnsOne(o => o.Competencia,
    sa =>
    {
        const string monthColumnName = "EMonth";
        const string yearColumnName = "Year";

        sa.Property(p => p.Month).HasColumnName(monthColumnName);
        sa.Property(p => p.Year).HasColumnName(yearColumnName);
    });

Notice that this problem happens even before any call to SaveChanges. Upon SaveChanges it indicates that the MyOwnedType property is required:

System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot save instance of 'MainEntity.MyOwnedTypeStart#MyOwnedType' because it is an owned entity without any reference to its owner. Owned entities can only be saved as part of an aggregate also including the owner entity.'

I've also tried adding the ThirdEntity directly to the DbSet before adding the MainEntity. Upon adding the ThirdEntity individually it doesn't lose the MyOwnedType value, but after that, when the MainEntity is also added to the context, the MyOwnedType property in the ThirdEntity are all set to null.
Edit: After adding log, I've found the following message:

warn: 30/05/2024 11:52:30.440 CoreEventId.DuplicateDependentEntityTypeInstanceWarning[10001] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update)
The same entity is being tracked as different entity types 'ThirdEntity.MyOwnedType#MyOwnedType' and 'MainEntity.CompetenciaStart#MyOwnedType' with defining navigations. If a property value changes, it will result in two store changes, which might not be the desired outcome.


The question doesn't contain code that saves to the database. Add doesn't add anything to the database, it attaches a new object in the Added state. A DbContext isn't a database connection, it's a Unit-of-Work and do.  Nothing is persisted until SaveChanges is called to store all changes to all tracked entities, not just the last one modified.

Side note: are you sure you need AddAsync? It's very likely that you should use Add.

There's no reason to use AddAsync either. AddAsync doesn't add. It's used to retrieve batches of database-generated IDs from the database when complex ID schemes are used like HiLo, or different clients/servers use a different range of preallocated IDs.

It's hard to propose a solution with just the code posted here because there's no code that sets MyOwnedType anywhere, nor is there any attempt to save. Please post enough code for others to reproduce the problem. DbContext.Add attaches the entity and all reachable detached objects in the Added state. That means that just setting all MyOwnedType properties before callling DbContext.Add(mainEntity) should be enough.

The DuplicateDependentEntityTypeInstanceWarning suggests the application code  is trying to reuse the same MyOwnedType instance. An owned type is supposed to be part of a single entity so it makes no sense for a part to belong to multiple entities. It's like saying my hand belongs is part of 2 other people.

The issue have been noticed before applying the context's changes on the database. The  property was beeing set to null in the object in the application memory, not in the database table.

There's nothing like asking to find the answer.
I've found that the problem is that I was using the same instance of MyOwnedType to populate both the SecondEntity and ThirdEntity. Despite that MyOwnedType is a record, it behaves as a reference type, so that EF ids it has beeing an owned type beeing referenced by multiple entities, which is not allowed.
Using the record's clone mechanism myOwnedType with {} have resolved the issue.
I wouldn't expect it to silently be set to null though.
